# Layout elements do not go to the next line

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to recreate a screen from an application. I am using a custom view which combines an image view with 3 text views. I then insert a bunch of these custom views into a scroll view's linear layout, however I can only see two of them and the rest do not appear (see picture).

XML of main activiry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingStart="16sp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textCaption="Apply and chat with our hosts"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textCaption="Boze Boze"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textCaption="Apply and chat with our hosts"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textCaption="Apply and chat with our hosts"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: two muppets]

UPDATE:

Changing the android:scrollbars property to vertical seemed to solve the poroblem but only places 1 image in each line.

Comment: Add _android:fillViewPort="true"_ for ScrollView.

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: Height will be _match_parent_ for Scrollview too.

Comment: Still, it does not work.

Comment: That's the intended behavior of a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Make linear layout match_parent. Hope this will work.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: It's not going to work because a `LinearLayout` doesn't have wrapping capabilities. You have a few options. 1) Manually placing the views where you want them, row by row. 2) `RecyclerView`

Comment: @glucaio is right. `LinearLayout` can't do what you want. There's third option: [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingStart="16sp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textCaption="Apply and chat with our hosts"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textCaption="Boze Boze"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>
</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textCaption="Apply and chat with our hosts"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>

        <com.example.knigoteka.BenefitView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            app:image="@drawable/jesus"
            app:textCaption="Apply and chat with our hosts"
            app:textAutor = "Vasko Vasilev"
            app:textPrice="420 ДЕН"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using RecyclerView and a custom layout. 
Custom layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="370px"
android:layout_height="740px"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="1dp"
android:layout_margin="30dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:id="@+id/parent_layout">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    tools:src="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:background="#010101"/>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Caption of the Book"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="#666"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/autor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Caption of the Book"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="#666"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/caption"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/autor"
    android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:text="Price of the Book"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:textColor="#666"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"/>
```